# One-line lambda function that sets a value to a variable

Tags: python, variables, lambda

Creating callback functions that set a variable `obj.x` like this:

```
def f(button, callback):
    pass

def callback1():
    obj.x = 1
def callback2():
    obj.x = 2

class Obj: 
    pass
obj = Obj()
f('abc', callback2)
f('def', callback1)
```

is redundant, and can be replaced by:

```
def xsetter(value):
    obj.x = value

f('abc', lambda: xsetter(1))
f('def', lambda: xsetter(2))
```

**Question: is there even simpler, without having to define a setter for `x`?** Is something similar to the following possible?

```
f('abc', lambda: obj.x = 1)
f('def', lambda: obj.x = 2)
```

Here it produces an error:

> SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment

Comment: `setattr()` should work. You can check its usage [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/setattr)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assignments to *names* aren't (cleanly) possible inside a lambda expression. You, however, are assigning to an *attribute*, which is handled by the `setattr` function.

```
f('abc', lambda: setattr(obj, 'x', 1))
```

You can also use `functools.partial` to "partially" apply the object's `__setattr__` method to the required arguments.

```
from functools import partial

f('abc', partial(obj.__setattr__, 'x', 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a `setattr`-related function that would work with such a syntax: `f('abc', lambda: setvalue(obj.x, 1))`  <-- such a syntax/API would be very clean

Comment: And more generally `f('abc', lambda: assign_variable(foo, 'bar'))` that would do `foo = 'bar'`?

Comment: No, because `obj.x` would first be evaluated to the current value of the attribute (or raise an `AttributeError`), rather than being treated as an lvalue.

Comment: Exactly @chepner, that's what I noticed too, it is evaluated first... Of course there is `f('abc', lambda: eval("foo = 'bar'"))` ;) but not sure `eval` can set variables. Anyway I won't use this, no `eval`!

Comment: You can use `globals()` to assign to global variables by name, but I strongly discourage you from doing so. You should reconsider your design if you find yourself thinking you need to do this.

Comment: I'll use `setattr` which is good for my problem. Just out of curiosity, how would you do with `globals()`? (I won't use this anyway).

Comment: `globals()` returns a `dict`, so you can so something like `globals().__setitem__('x', 3)`. For other variables, writing to the mapping returned by `locals()` isn't guaranteed to actually affect the local scope, and there is no equivalent for other non-local scopes. Other solutions (e.g., involving the `inspect` module) get even uglier.

Comment: Thanks for this info @chepner. `setattr` is perfect for my purpose.